# xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): -- while converting folder containing xml files to csv files

Tags: python, xml, csv, parse-error

this is the python script of converting sub-folder named test and train in the parent folder named images xml files to csv files
for object detection using tensorflow api for labelling the satellite images

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def xml_to_csv(path):
    xml_list = []
    for xml_file in glob.glob(path + '/*.xml'):
        tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
        root = tree.getroot()
        for member in root.findall('object'):
            value = (root.find('filename').text,
                     int(root.find('size')[0].text),
                      int(root.find('size')[1].text),
                       member[0].text,
                      int(member[4][0].text),
                 int(member[4][1].text),
                 int(member[4][2].text),
                 int(member[4][3].text)
                 )
         xml_list.append(value)
column_name = ['filename', 'width', 'height', 'class', 'xmin', 'ymin', 'xmax', 'ymax']
xml_df = pd.DataFrame(xml_list, columns=column_name)
return xml_df


def main():
for folder in ['train','test']:
    image_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), ('images/' + folder))
    xml_df = xml_to_csv(image_path)
    xml_df.to_csv(('images/' + folder + '_labels.csv'), index=None)
    print('Successfully converted xml to csv.')



main()
```

and getting this error

```
    File "xml_to_csv.py", line 37, in <module>
    main()
  File "xml_to_csv.py", line 31, in main
    xml_df = xml_to_csv(image_path)
  File "xml_to_csv.py", line 10, in xml_to_csv
    tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
  File "C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1196, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 597, in parse
     self._root = parser._parse_whole(source)
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 2,    column 5
```

I've tried to see if the encoding is not a problem, but it seems not making any effect on making error.
Here's the xml code out of 500 generated as a result of the labelling of satellite images.

```
<annotation>
<folder>train</folder>
<filename>windmill8.jpg</filename>
<path>C:/tensorflow1/models/research/object_detection/images/train/windmill8.jpg</path>
<source>
    <database>Unknown</database>
</source>
<size>
    <width>1538</width>
    <height>820</height>
    <depth>3</depth>
</size>
<segmented>0</segmented>
<object>
    <name>windmill</name>
    <pose>Unspecified</pose>
    <truncated>0</truncated>
    <difficult>0</difficult>
    <bndbox>
        <xmin>270</xmin>
        <ymin>713</ymin>
        <xmax>337</xmax>
        <ymax>766</ymax>
    </bndbox>
</object>
```

please tell how to fix this???

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the portion of the XML containing the invalid token.  Realize that certain characters such as NUL are not allowed in XML.